# Centering Variables in R

Tags: r, anova

Do centered variables have to stay in matrix form when using them in a regression equation?

I have centered a few variables using the `scale` function with `center=T` and `scale=F`. I then converted those variables to a numeric variable, so that I can manipulate the data frame for other purposes. However, when I run an ANOVA, I get slightly different F values, just for that variable, all else is the same.

Edit:

What's the difference between these two:

```
scale(df$A, center=TRUE, scale=FALSE)
```

Which will embed a matrix within your data.frame

AND

```
scale(df$A, center=TRUE, scale=FALSE)
df$A = as.numeric(df$A)
```

Which makes variable A numeric, and removes the matrix notation within the variable?

Example of what I am trying to do, but the example doesn't cause the problem I am having:

```
library(car)
library(MASS)
mtcars$wt_c <- scale(mtcars$wt, center=TRUE, scale=FALSE)
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars1     <- as.data.frame(mtcars)
# Part 1
rlm.mpg   <- rlm(mpg~wt_c+gear+wt_c*gear, data=mtcars1)
anova.mpg <- Anova(rlm.mpg, type="III")
# Part 2
# Make wt_c Numeric
mtcars1$wt_c <- as.numeric(mtcars1$wt_c)
rlm.mpg2     <- rlm(mpg~wt_c+gear+wt_c*gear, mtcars1)
anova.mpg2   <- Anova(rlm.mpg2, type="III")
```

Comment: What is A in the first example?

Comment: I'm pretty confused about what A is supposed to be. Is that a vector that is part of a data frame or a data frame itself?

Comment: A is just a variable, it is equivalent to mtcars$wt_c

Answer (score 0):

I'll attempt to answer both of your questions

1. > Do centered variables have to stay in matrix form when using them in a regression equation?

I'm not sure what you mean by this, but you can strip the center and scale attributes you get back from `scale()` if that is what you are referring to. You can see in the example below you get the same answer whether it is in 'matrix form' or not.

2. > What's the difference between these two:

> ```
> scale(A, center=TRUE, scale=FALSE)
> ```
>
> Which will embed a matrix within your data.frame
>
> AND
>
> ```
>  scale(df$A, center=TRUE, scale=FALSE)
>  df$A = as.numeric(df$A)
> ```

From the help file for `scale()` we see that it returns,

> "For scale.default, the centered, scaled matrix."

You are getting back a matrix with attributes for scaled and center. `as.numeric(AA)` strips off those attributes which is the difference between your first and second method. `c(AA)` does the same thing. I would guess `as.numeric()` either calls `c()` (through `as.double()`) or uses the same method it does.

```
 set.seed(1234)

 test <- data.frame(matrix(runif(10*5),10,5))

 head(test)
         X1        X2         X3        X4        X5
1 0.1137034 0.6935913 0.31661245 0.4560915 0.5533336
2 0.6222994 0.5449748 0.30269337 0.2651867 0.6464061
3 0.6092747 0.2827336 0.15904600 0.3046722 0.3118243
4 0.6233794 0.9234335 0.03999592 0.5073069 0.6218192
5 0.8609154 0.2923158 0.21879954 0.1810962 0.3297702
6 0.6403106 0.8372956 0.81059855 0.7596706 0.5019975

 # center and scale
 testVar <- scale(test[,1])

 testVar
             [,1]
 [1,] -1.36612292
 [2,]  0.48410899
 [3,]  0.43672627
 [4,]  0.48803808
 [5,]  1.35217501
 [6,]  0.54963231
 [7,] -1.74522210
 [8,] -0.93376661
 [9,]  0.64339300
[10,]  0.09103797
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 0.4892264
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 0.2748823

 # put testvar back with its friends
 bindVar <- cbind(testVar,test[,2:5])

 # run a regression with 'matrix form' y var
 testLm1 <- lm(testVar~.,data=bindVar)

 # strip non-name attributes
 testVar <- as.numeric(testVar)

 # rebind and regress
 bindVar <- cbind(testVar,test[,2:5])

 testLm2 <- lm(testVar~.,data=bindVar)

 # check for equality
 all.equal(testLm1, testLm2)
[1] TRUE
```

`lm()` seems to return the same thing so it appears they both are the same.

Comment: OK, maybe a better question then: If I center a variable, then switch it to numeric, then center it again, will those values change? I think I may have done then a few times by accident. Should any of the ANOVA output or coefficients change because of that?

Comment: No, nothing changes. And I don't have the problem now. Who knows what I did. I was using the `options` function to change the treatment level to contr.sum from contrl.trt, maybe that jazzed things up.

Comment: sometimes things get jazzed